# Devise registration "string not matched" with JsonB field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

When I remove the :location field, the form works.  However, I need to get it to store jsonb data.

## IndexError in RegistrationsController#create

> string not matched

```
 Extracted source (around line #151):

          if value != read(object, attribute, key)
            object.public_send :"#{attribute}_will_change!"
            object.public_send(attribute)[key] = value
          end
        end
```

## RegistrationsController

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected


  private 

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :location)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :location)
  end

end
```

## Schema

```
t.jsonb "interests", default: "{}", null: false
```

## MODEL

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  # These fields are within the interests jsonb field
  store_accessor :interests, :location

end
```

## FORM

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :location %>
    <%= f.text_field :location, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is with

> default: "{}"

In the migration. It needed to be

> {}

The former is a string, the latter a hash. You can not assign a key to a hash.

Comment: This save my night. Awesome!
Thanks